# Database Explorer replaced by Server explorer in vs 2010

Tags: c#, .net, sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

Folks

I see in VS 2005 its database explorer but I am not finding that in view in VS 2010. Is that server explorer ? Why they replaced if in case its replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell from this article it's the same thing with a different name.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x603htbk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this, I see through your link that its in Express edition displayed as DB Explorer where as in licensed edition its server explorer :) Thank you so much buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

They did not replace anything, you can find the same view as database explorer if you expand the data connection Icon in server explorer. Its bassically the same thing but you dont need teo windows to do almost the same things.

Answer (score 0):

**Source:** [Server Explorer/Database Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x603htbk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **Server Explorer/Database Explorer** is the server management console for Visual Studio. Use this window to open data connections and to log
>   on to servers and explore their databases and system services. In the
>   **Visual Studio Express products**, this window is named **Database Explorer**. In all other Visual Studio products, this window is named
>   **Server Explorer**.
>
> To access Server Explorer/Database Explorer, choose Server Explorer or
>   Database Explorer on the View menu.

Hope it help you.